# Php cron job in Task sheduler does not work in windows 2008

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I have problem with my task scheduler in windows 2008. It was working just fine while it was in 2003 but recently I have migrated from windows 2003 to windows 2008 server now the task scheduler is not working..

I have set my action parameter as below..

**C:\php\php.exe -q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs

  \dev.mysite.com.au\website\application\cronjobs\cronrun.php"**

I have checked with other settings as well all are seems fine..So could any one suggest me what could be the reason for this? thanks in advance..

Comment: Check the Task Scheduler Service is running, and run "C:\php\php.exe -q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs
\dev.mysite.com.au\website\application\cronjobs\cronrun.php" from command line to make sure that it works

Comment: Yes..I just tested it from command prompt as well..but it just returns nothing..Even though I was testing it by just echo some statement it does not do any thing..

Comment: Try using the relative path i.e. /public_html/home/yourscript rather than c:\.. you can add on the end of that string > C:\Logme.log and it will save the output  (if any) to log

Comment: Is this a new php install? Check the error settings for php. Have you done a http://localhost/... to check everything is working, php, mysql, apache, php script (ie php4->php5? depreciated functions) etc..